# Covariance knowning conditional distribution of the two variables

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, covariance

For an excercise at my university I need to find Var(X) where $X=(Y^t,Z^t)^t$ knowing that $Z \sim N(0,I_2)$ and $Y|Z \sim N(BZ,I_4)$ given that $B \in M_{4,2}$ is a matrix and the $I_2$ and $I_4$ are the identitis. I've managed to find that $Var(Y)=I_4+B^tB$ and I also already know $Var(Z)$, I am stuck at the $Cov(Y,Z)=E[YZ^t]$. Does someone know how to compute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sanity check: $B^t B$ is $2 \times 2$, so $I_4 + B^t B$ does not make sense.

---

The law of total variance implies
$$\text{Var}(Y) = E[\text{Var}(Y \mid Z)] + \text{Var}(E[Y \mid X]) = I_4 + \text{Var}(BZ) = I_4 + BE[ZZ^t] B^t = I_4 + BB^t.$$

---

Similarly, the [law of total covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_covariance) implies
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(Y,Z)
= E[\text{Cov}(Y, Z \mid Z)] + \text{Cov}(E[Y \mid Z], E[Z \mid Z])
= 0 + B = B.
\end{align}

Alternatively, letting $Y = BZ + U$ where $U \sim N(0, I_4)$ is independent of $Z$,
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(Y, Z)
&= E[(Y-E[Y])(Z-E[Z])^t]
\\
&= E[YZ^t]
\\
&= E[E[YZ^t \mid Z]]
\\
&= E[(BZ+U)Z^t]
\\
&= BE[ZZ^t] + B E[UZ^t]
\\
&= B.
\end{align}